# What could be causing "The application was unable to start correctly" error?

Tags: c++, error-handling, graphviz

I was trying to get started with graphviz libraries. So I tried to run the following code in Code::Blocks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gvc.h>
#include <cgraph.h>

using namespace std;


bool saveImageGV(std::string file_path){
    GVC_t *gvc;
    Agraph_t *g;
    FILE *fp;
    gvc = gvContext();
    fp = fopen((file_path+".dot").c_str(), "r");
    g = agread(fp, 0);
    gvLayout(gvc, g, "dot");
    gvRender(gvc, g, "png", fopen((file_path+".png").c_str(), "w"));
    gvFreeLayout(gvc, g);
    agclose(g);
    return (gvFreeContext(gvc));
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I've linked the cgraph and gvc librarires using "Build options..." in Code::Blocks. After running the program I got 0xC0150002 "The application was unable to start correctly" error(I will add the screenshot below). What could be causing it and how can I solve this problem ?
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean "The application was unable to start correctly"? You're probably missing DLL files in the directory where you're trying to run it. Be very specific about the error you're seeing, don't paraphrase.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I've edited the question to include screenshot and to make the name of the error specific. And yes, you're right, the specific phrase is "The application was unable to start correctly".